# In Ruby on Rails, how to make global constants autoreloadable in development mode, without server restart?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

E.g. Currently I put global constants in the `config/initializers/constants.rb` file, with this content:

```
KB = 1000
```

I want my app to immediately recognize `MB` when I add this line, without server restart:

```
MB = KB * KB
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initializers are designed to fire only once on the initialization of the app. If you want something reloadable, put it in a separate module inside `lib` folder. Here is a full topic about [Autoloading and Reloading Constants](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html):

> ```
>   module Colors
>     RED = '0xff0000'
>   end
> ```

Note, you will also have to adjust your application.rb with

```
 config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
```

So, for your case it would be a file constants.rb inside lib:

```
module Constants
  KB = 1000
end
```

Then in your class you can use your constant:

```
class Something
  include Constants
  MB = KB * KB
end
```

Here MB will change if you change the value of KB on page reload, and it will not require a restart.

Comment: * The idea is workable.
* It can work for all XxxController if the base class ApplicationController's body "include Constants".
* It can work for *.html.erb and all XxxHelper if ApplicationHelper's body "include Constants" and all other XxxHelper's body "include ApplicationHelper".

Comment: * Yet how can we make sure all app/models/*.rb can use the constant?  "include Constants" in all model class is not satisfactory enough...
* But still the answer is useful.

Comment: @JohnnyWong: Then switch to Rails 5. Over there all models are inherited from abstract ApplicationRecord, and it will be the place where you can include your constants. Also, I am kinda doubt that you want to include something everywhere uncontrollably. It may cause all kind of naming collisions and such.

Answer (score 0):

#### Inspired by the answer of gen, the solution below seems also work.

1. config/application.rb:

   ```
   ...
   config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
   ...
   ```
2. config/initializers/init_constants.rb:

   ```
   require 'constants'
   ```
3. lib/constants.rb

   ```
   KB = 1000
   MB = KB * KB
   ```
4. app/controllers/applicaton_controller.rb (after class ApplicationController):

   ```
   class ApplicationController ...
     ...
   end
   require_dependency 'constants' if Rails.env.development?
   ```

The constants seems auto-reloaded on every request.

Not quite sure why it works.

Comment: I think step 2 is not needed.

Comment: @AshishBista Yes, it can be optional.  However, it may depend on whether the constants are needed at configuration & initialization phrase?

Comment: I doubt if step 2 is omitted, other classes using `KB` will be undefined before ApplicationController is loaded.  I think ApplicationController may not always be the first autoloading-class loaded.  But yes, the code left a double definition of constants warnings at early app initilization.

Comment: I believe step 1 take care of all these things.

Comment: @AshishBista I checked that most often it works.  Some less-often cases will not work, e.g. when you need to do something that depend on some of the constant in certain config/initializers/*.rb file.  One simple example is replacing `require 'constants'` by `puts "#{KB}"` in step 2.  Thus, I think it is ok to keep that line of code at early initialization.  :)